# Strange Error launch Java (Eclypse)

Tags: java, launch

I read the discussions about this problem, but I couldn't find a solution for it!

I wrote a very easy program, but as I launch it, this error appears:

```
           << Selection does not contain a main type >>
```

Thank you very much in advance to whom will help me. I am new of Java:/

---

```
public class Implementation{

  public static void Main(String args[]){

    Operations_numbers operations;
    operations = new Operations_numbers();

    int subtraction = operations.subtraction(10,2);
    String result_Comparison = new String();
    result_Comparison = operations.comparison(8,3);

    System.out.println(result_Comparison); 
    System.out.println(subtraction); 

  }

}
---------------
public class Operations_numbers{

  public int subtraction (int x, int y){
    int subtraction;
    subtraction=x-y; 
    return subtraction;
  }

  public String comparison (int x, int y){    
    if(x>y){    
      String result="the number" + x + "is bigger than the number" + y;
      return result;
    }    
    else{  
      String result="the number" + y + "is bigger than the numbero" + x;
      return result;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`main` should be lowercase. The proper signature is

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

Comment: thank you very much all of you guys! you were very very fast!!!

Now I am ashamed of my question, it was a very little and stupid detail. 

I hope I can give you my help in the future, when I will become a good programmer too!

andrea

Answer (score 0):

Function names are case sensitive. As the error message suggests it can't find the main function. However you defined a Main function. Try it with lowercase main. :)

Comment: thank you very much all of you guys! you were very very fast!!! Now I am ashamed of my question, it was a very little and stupid detail. I hope I can give you my help in the future, when I will become a good programmer too! andrea

Answer (score 0):

You have to change

```
public static void Main(String args[]) {/* code */}
```

to

```
public static void main(String args[]) { /* code */ }
```

Because java is case sensitive and expect a method called main, in downcase, as entry point.

Comment: thank you very much all of you guys! you were very very fast!!! Now I am ashamed of my question, it was a very little and stupid detail. I hope I can give you my help in the future, when I will become a good programmer too! andrea